# Do I need to buy license for kendo angular 2 UI for open source project?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

My project is open source (not making any $$).

Is it okay to use kendoUI for angular2 without purchasing license?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI for Angular is a commercial product that requires a license in order to use it in production. More details can be found in `Licensing and Pricing` section:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/

I suppose that you can get the most accurate answer if you contact Telerik sales representative directly:

http://www.telerik.com/contact